# How can Integrate Google Lab or Jupyter Lab in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In here below, I show a dashboard with some modules that will be built on react. When I click on the module called Data Lab, I want to be able to see Jupyter Lab or Google-Colab?

Any suggestion on how to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtM50.png)

[image]

Comment: did you find a way?